# Adobe Analytics - increased number of server calls alert

Tags: adobe-analytics

Is it possible to set an alert, which will inform about increased number of primary server calls in Adobe Analytics?

In the alerts section of AA I can't find any metric, which would allow to get such information.

Answer (score 2):

You can *kind of* get it by using a calculated metric. It would be defined as:

`Page Views + Custom Links + Download Links + Exit Links`

From there, run that calculated metric report and set an alert for it. Note that this will not include excluded hits, such as those from bot traffic or your 'exclude by IP' filter.

Comment: This is a nice trick, but it's silly that Adobe doesn't allow to check such data on a daily basis (AA users are charged for server calls!)